# Converting Map<String, List<Integer>> to Map<String, int[]>

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Having a data map as below :

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> dataMap = ....
```

i want to convert it to another Map

below, the solution I've tried

```
Map<String, int[]> dataMapOut = new HashMap<>();
dataMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    int[] val = entry.getValue().stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
    dataMapOut.put(key, val);
});
```

Looking for better and more concise way of mapping ?

Comment: Question is: why would you want to replace a `List` with an array? Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: @Turing85 - There is one API which returns Map of List and need to call another API which expects map of int[]; so writing an adapter.

Answer (score 10):

You're looking for the [`toMap` collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-).

```
 Map<String, int[]> result = dataMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    e -> e.getValue()
                            .stream()
                            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                            .toArray()));
```

Comment: Tried exactly same but Eclipse was not auto-suggesting getValue; so I thought I am doing something wrong :(

Comment: @javaq I use IntelliJ IDEA so not sure how good the eclipse IDE is. but at least now we know next time eclipse doesn't help you out, maybe you can continue until there is a compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

With streams, use `Collectors.toMap` and `Arrays.setAll` to create the array from each `List`:

```
Map<String, int[]> dataMapOut = dataMap.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        e -> {
            int[] arr = new int[e.getValue().size()];
            Arrays.setAll(arr, e.getValue()::get);
            return arr;
        }));
```

Without streams, using `Map.forEach` along with `Arrays.setAll`:

```
Map<String, int[]> dataMapOut = new HashMap<>();
dataMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
    int[] arr = new int[v.size()];
    Arrays.setAll(arr, v::get);
    dataMapOut.put(k, arr);
});
```

---

Or, if you want to be succinct:

```
Map<String, int[]> map = new HashMap<>();
dataMap.forEach((k, v) -> map.put(k, v.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution can be like this:

```
Map<String,int[]> result= map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(m->new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(m.getKey(),m.getValue()
                   .stream()
                   .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                   .toArray()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,entry->entry.getValue(),(e1,e2)->e1,LinkedHashMap::new));
```